# SQL query for determining which grouped row is True

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb, grafana

I have the following database structure

```
datetime:datetime|id:id|result:bool|s_num:string|name:string
```

Sample of db

```
Datetime  |id  |result  | s_num  |name
__________________________________________
12.01.2022|2   |False   | a21    | test_1
13.01.2022|3   |False   | a22    | test_1
15.01.2022|51  |True    | a21    | test_1
16.01.2022|3   |False   | a22    | test_1
17.01.2022|3   |True    | a22    | test_1
```

Basically, I need to group every `s_num` then tell which entry of it (ordered by `datetime`
where the oldest means first) is True. For provided Sample output would be

```
s_num  |name  |after_which
___________________________
a21    |test_1|2
a22    |test_1|3
```

Because the second row of `s_num` with value of `a21` was True. I was thinking of lateral, but MariaDB doesn't support it. I tried numbering rows with `ROW_COUNT()` and `over` but my MariaDB version is too low. Furthermore, I can't think of any solution. If I could use python I would get all serial_numbers, then use for loop for every serial_number and check which row has value of True, but I want to use it for `Grafana`. For Grafana I was thinking about 10 queries, each for checking 1 row number.

Comment: It's possible to emumlate the ROWNUM window function in older MySQL versions. For example [read this](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/). You will also need to put your date/time variables in standard database format. `2022-01-12` rather than `12-01.2022` to get the results you need. And MariaDB / MySQL doesn't have any native Boolean data type. Nonzero integers are considered true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your question is not that very clear to me.
Does this provide you your result?

```
SELECT 
  s.s_sum,
  s.name ,
  (SELECT COUNT(*)+1 FROM sample_db s1 WHERE s1.s_sum=s.s_sum AND s1.datetime<s.datetime AND s1.result=FALSE) after_which
FROM
  `sample_db` s 
  WHERE s.result=TRUE
GROUP BY s.s_sum
```